# Retrieving an app's DockTile (view)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm getting my hands dirty with a bit of ObjC by trying to write something Dock-like, with a little less visual bells and whistles. It's going pretty well. However I've stumbled over a problem which I can't quiet solve:

Retrieving an app's icon via `NSRunningApplication` is easy. However, some apps don't use their icon as `DockTile`, they [use a custom view](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html) because their DockTiles are dynamic (f.e. most torrent apps display their current up/down speeds in the dock).

Is there any way to get this `DockTile` and display it in my own app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. The methods which set a custom dock tile end up communicating the contents of the view directly to the Dock; it is not made available to other processes.

For what it's worth, writing a replacement for the Dock is going to be a kind of hopeless task -- Apple's Dock.app uses numerous private, undocumented APIs to interact with the WindowServer, some of which simply cannot be used by any process which is not the Dock.